# Playing a sound in one component plays it in all components

Tags: angular

I have multiple components/route which I have implemented.

I have configured Howl to play on only 1 route on loop.

Now when I navigate to ANY route the audio file starts playing. If I navigate to another route the same audio file keeps playing. It seems like file is being reference global.

I've tried stopping the file in other routes that don't require it to be played but that doesn't do anything.

```
sound = new Howl({
src: ['../../../assets/audio/background/piano.wav'],
autoplay: true,
loop: true,
volume: 0.5,
onend() {
  console.log('Finished!');
},
onloaderror() {
    console.log('Error!');
},
});

ngOnInit() {
  sound.play();
}
```

Only play the audio file in a given route, not across the entire app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ngOnDestroy() {
  this.sound.stop();
}
```

Comment: Or you should probably unload instead of just calling stop.